# Not able to render on IE9 with angularjs - 1.2

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I have this piece of code to render categories.

```
<ul role="menuitem" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button" >
    <li ng-repeat="x in SuperCategories | orderBy:'name'" >
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="changeSuperCategory(x)">{{x.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The code is working fine in mozzile and chrome and IE10. But not in IE9 or below.

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: do you have <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">?

Comment: I have like this `
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <!--[if IE 8]><!--> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> <!--<![endif]-->
  `

Comment: @ kornieff. I tried with your suggestion also. But still not rendering.

Comment: remove if ie8 conditional and replace it with <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">. Ie8 does not work in ie8 anyway